# Using sed can't replace text in file with contents of variable

Tags: sed

I have $subs variable and bbb file.

**$subs variable contents:**

```
echo $subs
http://somesite21.something.com:8088/premier-esb-emulator-app/services/es bServiceStub
```

**bbb file contents:**

```
BBBBbbbAAAAA
```

The command I try to use:

```
sed "s|bb|${subs}|" bbbb
```

But it doesn't work, error output:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 85: unterminated `s' command
```

**Please advise. Thanks in advance!**

Comment: What does `declare -p subs` output?

Comment: declare -p subs
  
declare --      subs="http://somesite21.something.com:8088/premier-esb-emulator-app/services/es bServiceStub      "

Comment: Put it in the post (instead of the `echo` output if you want) and make sure to get the formatting correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

subs="http://somesite21.something.com:8088/premier-esb-emulator-app/services/es bServiceStub"

sed "s|bb|${subs}|" bbb
```

This is how bbb file looks like:

```
BBBBbbbAAAAA
```

and here is the output:

[image]

I know it is a bad answer, but it seems to be working for me.

**__UPDATE__**

Let's see If I got you right:

- Assuming your working environment is unix-like
- Jenkins sets a variable, namely subs. I assumed it is an exported var
- You need to replace some part of a file, called bbb.
- Substitution would be a single line of code.

So, this still works for me:
[image]

Am I missing something ?

**__UPDATE_II__**

I think I found the problem in your case: the way you set the env variable. Please look at my console output below and pay extra attention to the way I set subs var from output.txt file. It works the way I did it so it should work on your side too.

[image: console: reading subs from output.txt]

I decided too add commands here for your convenience:

```
cat output.txt
export subs=`cat output.txt`
echo ${subs}
sed "s|bb|${subs}|" bbb
```

Let's hope this time it will work for you =]

Comment: Thanks for reply but it's not what I'm looking for, though it works.

Comment: Then I am not clear what you are asking for. Could you clarify your question please.

Comment: I need to substitute some part of text in bbb file with contents of subs variable. subs variable will be generated automatically using Jenkins job. So substitution needs to be a single line code. Am I clear?

Comment: What I actually do first is - subs=$(cat output1.txt), that's how I get this variable. The problem is that I get a specific value from Oracle DB and export it in a file called "output1.txt". I didn't find any working example to make sed read from file so I put it into variable. But if I use variable likeso: sed "s|bb|${subs}|" bbb; it doesn't work. Thank you so much for helping me to solve it! Waiting for your reply!

Comment: @Gleb I will be glad if I could help =] Please see my 2nd update above. I think this time we nailed it =]

Comment: sed command gives an error...:'( output is: sed: -e expression #1, char 85: unterminated `s' command....

Comment: interesting. did you copy/paste the commands I have in my answer ? **If NOT**, please do copy/paste. **If so**, what is your env ? Linux? OSX ?

Comment: OK. Good news. At least we are getting somewhere.! =D now let's find out what's the diff between your server and wherever else you're running it.

Comment: Well, beats me. at least we got it working on the server. You gotto figure out what is different on the other one. User? Rights ? goodness knows what. =] Good luck.

Comment: pluse-uno for tech support /-;